Autofs expiring browseable offset mounts, resulting in the inability to mount
Summary: 
We define a /mount/path/pathcontd/mountpoint tree in autofs, have historically --ghosted the paths, but have recently attempted to set the offset mounts as browse-able. 
Our configuration works great... at first. Once the timeout hits (I set this to 10s for debugging... but normally have it set to 300s), the autofs (type) mount points start expiring. Once this expiration starts, the offset mounts disappear (often leaving one mount point remaining that is broken). The disappeared mount points are unable to be re-mounted.
Config: 
distro Name: Rocky Linux 8.8 (Green Obsidian) 
autofs-5.1.4-102.el8_8.2 
NFS4.{0..2}(though... the nfs mounts are not being invoked when this issue happens.)
Autofs configs:
/mounts/prog/lty/ion  /etc/auto.prog_lty tcp hard timeo=600 retrans=2 async browse

lty -nfsvers=4,minorversion=1 /inc         isi1:/ifs/inc/ai/lty \
                        /0300             isi1:/ifs/prog/lty/ion/0300 \
                        /mfi        isi1:/ifs/prog/lty/ion/mfi \
                        /gen        isi1:/ifs/prog/lty/ion/gen

What this looks like: 
Working:
ls /mounts/prog/lty/ion
/mounts/prog/lty/ion:
0300  mfi  gen

Broken:
ls /mounts/prog/lty/ion
    /mounts/prog/lty/ion
    mfi

Statting of this path results in a wedged terminal, the autofs mount still is showing however:
/etc/auto.prog_lty on /mounts/prog/lty/ion/mfi type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=103,pgrp=6383,timeout=10,minproto=5,maxproto=5,offset,pipe_ino=102821)

I claim that the autofs mounts should not be expiring at all... and that I want mounted NFS sessions to umount after timeout. Stopping autofs results in a loop of trying to umount the remaining autofs shares until it hits a timeout and gets killed.
The remaining autofs mounts return busy when umount -a -t autofs (or the session locks up). lsof and fuser show 0 processes using the mount point.
4 D root        7929    7805  0  80   0 -  6329 autofs 09:37 pts/2    00:00:00 umount -a -t autofs

What I have tried: 
I was originally distracted by the idea that this was a fileserver issue... testing different versions of NFS etc. But after seeing 0 nfs mounts happening... I am more convinced that this is a bug in my config, or autofs. The variations of --ghost vs. browseable have yielded no differences here. The same bug repros on Centos7.9 with an earlier version of autofs. \
Setting timeout to 0 fixes this, but then no NFS mounts expire... and holding open hundreds/thousands of mounts on every system (hundreds) seems rather problematic.
Any thoughts/ideas/similar experiences/ideas on how to debug further?
